# How to use itertools.groupby when the key value is in the elements of the iterable?

Tags: python, group-by, python-itertools

To illustrate, I start with a list of 2-tuples:

```
import itertools
import operator

raw = [(1, "one"),
       (2, "two"),
       (1, "one"),
       (3, "three"),
       (2, "two")]

for key, grp in itertools.groupby(raw, key=lambda item: item[0]):
    print key, list(grp).pop()[1]
```

yields:

```
1 one
2 two
1 one
3 three
2 two
```

In an attempt to investigate why:

```
for key, grp in itertools.groupby(raw, key=lambda item: item[0]):
    print key, list(grp)

# ---- OUTPUT ----
1 [(1, 'one')]
2 [(2, 'two')]
1 [(1, 'one')]
3 [(3, 'three')]
2 [(2, 'two')]
```

Even this will give me the same output:

```
for key, grp in itertools.groupby(raw, key=operator.itemgetter(0)):
    print key, list(grp)
```

I want to get something like:

```
1 one, one
2 two, two
3 three
```

I am thinking this is because the key is within the tuple inside the list, when in fact the tuple gets moved around as one. Is there a way to get to my desired output? Maybe `groupby()` isn't suited for this task?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`groupby` clusters *consecutive* elements of the iterable which have the same key.
To produce the output you desire, you must first sort `raw`.

```
for key, grp in itertools.groupby(sorted(raw), key=operator.itemgetter(0)):
    print key, map(operator.itemgetter(1), grp)

# 1 ['one', 'one']
# 2 ['two', 'two']
# 3 ['three']
```

Comment: I thought `grp` is an `itertool._grouper` object. What other kinds of  `builtin` actions can I do with a `_grouper`? I see that you treated it like an `iterable` as well? Neat!

Comment: @Kit: I believe the main useful fact about `grp` is that it is an `iterable`. Until you mentioned it, I didn't know it was an `itertools._grouper` object. This seems to be a good example of the convenience of duck-typing. We don't need to know the type of `grp`, only that it implements the `iterable` interface.

Comment: I would use `itemgetter(0)` for `sorted` as well, just for explicitness

Answer (score 7):

I think a cleaner way to get your desired result is this.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d=defaultdict(list)
>>> for k,v in raw:
...  d[k].append(v)
... 
>>> for k,v in sorted(d.items()):
...  print k, v
... 
1 ['one', 'one']
2 ['two', 'two']
3 ['three']
```

building `d` is O(n), and now `sorted()` is just over the unique keys instead of the entire dataset

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

> The operation of groupby() is similar
>   to the uniq filter in Unix. It
>   generates a break or new group every
>   time the value of the key function
>   changes (which is why it is usually
>   necessary to have sorted the data
>   using the same key function). That
>   behavior differs from SQL’s GROUP BY
>   which aggregates common elements
>   regardless of their input order.

Since you are sorting the tuples lexicographically anyway, you can just call `sorted`:

```
for key, grp in itertools.groupby( sorted( raw ), key = operator.itemgetter( 0 ) ):
    print( key, list( map( operator.itemgetter( 1 ), list( grp ) ) ) )
```

Comment: Removing the spaces around the parentheses would make me feel warm and fuzzy inside ;)

Comment: I am a believer in \t\n    \n, the Lord of Whitespace. He tells me that PEP-8 is wrong, and the world needs more whitespace!